# Compatibility with different versions of QGIS and Mac OS

Tags: osx, compatibility

I use QGIS 2.1.0 and Mac OS 10.7.5. If I update to OS Yosemite or El Capitan when it's released this fall; do I risk compatibility problems with my version of QGIS? Or if I update to the newest version of QGIS; do I risk compatibility problems with my present projects?

Comment: This is probably a better question for the [QGIS forums](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Quantum-GIS-User-f4125267.html); there are a lot of compatibility discussions there.